# Resizing scrollbar in Designer for Win Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm totally new to Win Forms.  I see that the vertical scroll bar on the right hand side for someone else's code does not reach the bottom right corner.  You'd think I'd be able to just grab it and resize it.  However, I'm not able to do it.  I don't see a two-sided arrow that usually indicates resize.  There is a vertical spacer on top of it if that makes a difference.  Also in the properties window, I cannot change the height to make it longer.  Is it locked somehow that I'm unaware of and cannot make the changes?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the panel or control that has the scrollbar is not sized, anchored or docked correctly. This would result in it existing underneath the bounds of a maximised form and therefore inaccessible.

Try making sure that in the designer its bounds are correctly within the form and the anchoring and docking values are logical. Otherwise, consider viewing its .Size and .Location properties in the debugger to see if it is too far "south".

Comment: ...or maybe the form controls are locked.